# How to make a regular expression for doule quotes in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following string which I have to pass to mysql_query() function. This sting is generated dynamically when somebody tries to search some data in my site. Now the problem is there is no ending quotes after each word.

```
and purpose="Buy and property_type="Home and property_nature="Residential and city =" Lahore"
```

I want this string to be in this form:

```
and purpose="Buy" and property_type="Home" and property_nature="Residential" and city =" Lahore"
```

Thanks

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you just want to use `addslashes()` - regex is not required to escape quotes

Comment: I should mention that you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions - they are deprecated and have security issues. You should migrate your code to `MySQLi` or `PDO`, and make use of prepared statements

Comment: Instead of expanding your code with more bad habbits/old deprecated libraries, consider using PDO or MySQLi instead as these would not have a problem with quotes variables AT ALL, and you are much more secure against PHP upgrades/SQL injections (use prepared queries and ound variables).

Comment: Sorry I dont need addslashes here. I only need " after every word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I want my string to be in this form

and purpose="Buy" and property_type="Home" and property_nature="Residential" and city =" Lahore"

Comment: Why don't you replace " and " with "\" and "   ?

Comment: Please update your question with an unmistakably clear explanation of your *input*, your *desired output*, why you desire this output and what problem you have in creating it. It's not clear to me what the goal is here and sounds like a possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: **Don't** use `mysql_` family of functions! They are deprecated and insecure.  Use PDO instead. That said, how did you manage to create a string like that?  If you are building this query string yourself, then just build it correctly.

Comment: Ok I am updating my question now .

Comment: Why *isn't* your string in that form to begin with?! Why do you have such weird half quotes? That needs fixing at the root, not afterwards!

Comment: I have updated my question. Now it will be more clear to you.

Comment: How do you make this string? Just add `"`'s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing why you would want to do this and not just fix the string when you create it, you're probably looking for a regex such as `/(?<!") and/` using a *negative lookbehind*:

```
$string = 'and purpose="Buy and property_type="Home" and property_nature="Residential and city =" Lahore"';
$string = preg_replace('/(?<!") and/', $string);
var_dump($string);
```

Which gives

> and purpose="Buy" and property_type="Home" and property_nature="Residential" and city =" Lahore"

[**Codepad demo**](http://codepad.org/x5Zfj9CX).

[**Regex 101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dI7nS2)

This also automatically doesn't change `"Home" and` to `"Home"" and` as it makes sure that there isn't a quote already.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements. Perhaps something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ... WHERE ... AND purpose = :purpose AND property_type = :property_type AND property_nature = :property_nature AND city = :city');

$stmt->bindParam(':purpose',         $_POST[...]);
$stmt->bindParam(':property_type',   $_POST[...]);
$stmt->bindParam(':property_nature', $_POST[...]);
$stmt->bindParam(':city',            $_POST[...]);

$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use old API, the solution is [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Though, I recommend looking at newer approaches and binding of variables.